# What is the minimum indoor CO2 concentration that is achievable using houseplants?

Tags: home, plants, carbon-sequestration, co2

CO2 concentration is linked to health risks and even [our ability to think well](https://www.yaleclimateconnections.org/2016/07/indoor-co2-dumb-and-dumber/).  Meanwhile, [houseplants decrease CO2 concentration](http://www.pjoes.com/Measuring-the-Impact-of-Selected-Plants-on-Indoor-CO2-Concentrations,61744,0,2.html)  when they [receive enough sunlight](https://www.matec-conferences.org/articles/matecconf/pdf/2017/17/matecconf_iscee2017_05004.pdf).

However, both houseplant studies linked above used air with CO2 concentrations much higher than the current atmospheric concentration, and achieved reductions of CO2 that were still higher than the current atmospheric concentration.  For example, the first study saw plants decreasing CO2 from 3,310ppm to 732ppm, whereas the current atmospheric concentration is just above 400ppm.

My question: How low of an indoor CO2 concentration can be achieved using houseplants? Is it possible to get anywhere close to the ice age concentration of 200ppm?

Comment: According to [research from Turkey](http://www.pjoes.com/The-Effect-of-Some-Indoor-Ornamental-Plants-non-CO2-Levels-During-the-Day,76243,0,2.html), yucca can reduce CO2 concentrations from over 3,000 to 475ppm in a day in a 0.5 m3 sealed glass enclosure.

Comment: @LShaver That's awesome, but what I really want to know is whether the concentration could fall any further over more days?

Comment: The experiment ran for 5 days and the level never dropped below 475 ppm. I'd post this as an answer but I can't find any corroborating research. It's also a bit concerning that of 30 references, 23 are self-citations.

Comment: Are you keeping in mind that plant respiration _produces_ CO₂ around the clock?  So the bulk of any CO₂ removed from the air during the day via photosynthesis is returned at night via respiration?  Over the long run, the whole process is neutral.  That's why terrariums are possible.  You'll only have a noteworthy amount of CO₂ removed if you move the plants out of the house at night-time.

Comment: @Tim not quite the bulk, as some is incorporated into the plant structure, which over time gives us lovely coal/oil/gas to use for planet-destroying purposes.

Comment: @Tim moving the plants out of the house at night sounds like an excellent way to increase the efficiency of this process! I wonder how much it would help.

Comment: @LShaver Whole-plant respiration accounts for a little less than half of the CO₂ under global ambient conditions, but doubles for every ~10°C increase in temperature.  If you take plants from outside (~14°C global average) and put them inside (~20–21°C comfortable indoor temperature) then whole-plant respiration accounts for significantly more than half.  Ergo 'bulk'.  That's why tropical forests are anaemic compared to temperate forests (store less than half the carbon).  If memory serves, you need a ~16°C (average) temperature for CO₂ to be split 50:50 between respiration and structure.

Comment: @krubo Actually moving the plants would be impractical, I think.  You could, however, build a lean-to greenhouse/sun-room on one side of your house, have it open to the house during the day, and have it open to the outside at night.  The stationary plants would then act as a pump, and all you need to do is open/close some louvres/vents/windows/doors at sunrise/sunset.  You see this sort of feature on some passive solar homes (e.g. https://c1.staticflickr.com/1/89/274930313_f0cc51cf85_b.jpg and https://offgridworld.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/greenhouse-homeheating1.jpg).

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is no, not anywhere close to 200ppm and not appreciably lower than ambient conditions.  The modern standard for buildings is a full air change every three hours.  This means your houseplants would need to achieve your target level on a full house volume of air every three hours.  There is no practical arrangement which will achieve this.

The long answer is ...

[The photosynthesis equation is](https://www.thefarmersdaughterusa.com/2015/08/average-calories-per-acre.html) 6CO<sub>2</sub> + 6H<sub>2</sub>O ------> C<sub>6</sub>H<sub>12</sub>O<sub>6</sub> + 6O<sub>2</sub>.

Corn one of the most efficient photosynthetic producers of calories.  It can produce [15 million kilocalories per acre](https://www.thefarmersdaughterusa.com/2015/08/average-calories-per-acre.html) under good conditions.  That's 1.5 * 10<sup>10</sup> calories.

Let's say you have a 5x5x3m house.

You have floorspace for 25m<sup>2</sup> of field corn (you will just have to fit yourself in somehow).  An acre is 4,046 m<sup>2</sup> so 25m<sup>2</sup> is 25 / 4046 of an acre, or 0.6%.  So you can produce 6 * 10<sup>-3</sup> * 1.5 * 10<sup>10</sup> calories in this setting.  That's 9 * 10<sup>7</sup> calories.  Let's say you take really good care of the corn and manage 1 * 10<sup>8</sup> calories.

A gram of glucose provides 4 * 10<sup>3</sup> calories of energy when used.  So the amount of glucose that contains 10<sup>8</sup> calories is (10<sup>8</sup> calories / 4 * 10<sup>3</sup> calories), or 2.5 * 10<sup>5</sup> grams.

[The molar mass of glucose is 1.80 * 10<sup>2</sup> g mol<sup>-1</sup>.](https://www.adichemistry.com/qb/general/stoichiometry/1-moles-glucose.html)  Therefore there are 1 g / 1.80 * 10<sup>2</sup> g mol<sup>-1</sup> gives the number of glucose molecules in a gram - around 5 * 10<sup>-3</sup> mols or 3.3 * 10<sup>21</sup> molecules.

2.5 * 10<sup>5</sup> grams of glucose is therefore 3.3 * 10<sup>21</sup> molecules/gram * 2.5 * 10<sup>5</sup> grams = 8.2 * 10<sup>26</sup> molecules of glucose.

Each molecule of glucose requires 6 molecules of CO<sub>2</sub> to create.   8.2 * 10<sup>26</sup> molecules of glucose times 6 is around 5 * 10<sup>27</sup> molecules of CO<sub>2</sub>.  This is how many molecules of CO<sub>2</sub> will be removed from the air by the corn in your house over the course of a growing season.

It takes a growing season to use this much CO<sub>2</sub>.  There are around 10<sup>2</sup> days in a growing season.  So each day your corn will take 5 * 10<sup>25</sup> molecules of CO<sub>2</sub> out of the air for you.

[A human breaths out about 40000ppm CO2 which comes to about 1.27 * 10<sup>3</sup> grams of CO<sub>2</sub> per day.](https://www.quora.com/How-much-carbon-dioxide-does-the-average-person-exhale-in-a-day)  Given the molar weight of CO<sub>2</sub>, this is around 1.27 * 10<sup>3</sup> g / 1.17 * 10<sup>2</sup> g mol<sup>-1</sup> or 1 * 10<sup>1</sup> moles of CO<sub>2</sub>, or 6 * 10<sup>23</sup> molecules of CO<sub>2</sub>.

You have an air volume of 75m<sup>3</sup>.  [At a concentration of 440ppm, under somewhat normal conditions, there are about 2.5 * 10<sup>25</sup> * (440/1000000) molecules of CO<sub>2</sub> in a m<sup>3</sup> of air, or around 10<sup>22</sup> molecules.](https://www.reddit.com/r/theydidthemath/comments/55fkre/request_if_atmospheric_co2_just_hit_440ppm_how/)  So in your house you have 7.5 * 10<sup>23</sup> molecules of CO<sub>2</sub>.  If you use about half of these you'll reduce the concentration to 200ppm.

So to bring the concentration of CO<sub>2</sub> in the house from 440ppm to 200ppm with 75m<sup>2</sup> of corn growing and 1 human breathing will take:

(amount CO<sub>2</sub> to remove) / ((rate of removal) - (rate of addition))

or

(1.25 * 10<sup>25</sup> molecules CO<sub>2</sub>) / ((5 * 10<sup>25</sup> molecules CO<sub>2</sub> / day) - (6 * 10<sup>23</sup> molecules of CO<sub>2</sub>))

The human contribution ends up being pretty negligible (around 1% of the corn contribution) so we can drop it.

Thus

(1.25 * 10<sup>25</sup> molecules CO<sub>2</sub>) / (5 * 10<sup>25</sup> molecules CO<sub>2</sub> / day)

or 0.25 days, or 6 hours.

This is about half the rate you need to achieve a steady state of 200ppm in the house.  I've also assumed rate of use of CO<sub>2</sub> due to photosynthesis does not fall as CO<sub>2</sub> concentration falls (which it probably does).

Given that it's not very likely anyone wants to live in what amounts to an indoor corn field, any practical use of houseplants to alter CO<sub>2</sub> is likely to have negligible effects.

Given the rates figured here, you can decide how much of your household you are willing to devote to corn, determine the reduced rate, and figure out what the equilibrium CO<sub>2</sub> level will come to (very roughly, of course).  You may also want to adjust for other CO<sub>2</sub> sources such as higher or lower inside/outside air exchange rate (for a leaky house or a poorly built office, respectively), combustion products (cooking, etc).

Comment: +1. In the U.S., the [energy code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Energy_Conservation_Code) used in many jurisdictions mandates three air changes **per hour** in most climates. Restrictions are even looser in warmer climates.

Comment: Your calculations are very interesting. I hadn't realized the huge impact of air changes. So for my plan to be feasible, I'll have to reengineer the house to reduce air change with the outdoors. I now think the project could be doable if I build a greenhouse on my roof and allow it to interchange air with the house, while reducing air interchange with the outside atmosphere.

Comment: @krubo you'll need to maintain a balance between limiting air changes and allowing proper ventilation. Take a look at [Passive House](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passive_house) for guidelines on air sealing. They recommend 0.4 to 0.6 air changes per hour.

Comment: If you reduce air changes with the outside, you have to manage all other contents of the air in the house.  CO2 is not the only one.  Carbon monoxide and radon are two others that readily come to mind.  The outside environment is a giant dumping ground where all of these toxins can be diluted to the point of harmlessness (we hope - at least until we dump so much of them that they become a problem, like we've done with CO2).  If you cut yourself off from the dump to solve a CO2 issue, you may have created more problems than you've solved.

Comment: "the energy code used in many jurisdictions mandates three air changes per hour in most climates" - thanks, I always forget if it is 1 every 3 or 3 every 1.

Comment: I have a doubt about the calculation of human exhalation. Suppose a human metabolizes about 2000 kilocalories in a day, for simplicity let's suppose all carbohydrates, so equivalent to 500g of glucose, times avogadro's number divided by 180 mol-1 = 1.6 x 10^24 molecules of glucose. Aerobic catabolism of a molecule of glucose releases 6 molecules of CO2, which suggests that a breathing human should emit around 1 x 10^25 total molecules of CO2 per day. Intuitively it makes sense that I should have to grow enough corn to live on in order to absorb the CO2 I emit from metabolizing it.

Comment: @krubo That's a good point.  I was surprised the human contribution wasn't greater - so perhaps that part of the math or some assumption it is based on is flaky.  I'll try to revisit it sometime soon.

Comment: @Jean-PaulCalderone I think I found two errors which explain the difference. It looks like 1.27 * 10^-3 should be 1.27 * 10^3. And 3.3 x 10^22 should be 3.3 x 10^21.

Comment: Thanks.  I think you're right on both counts.  The human contribution still comes out to around 1% of what the corn is doing so there may be more issues.  Separately, I realized I have only accounted for the human edible carbon stored by the corn.  There's a lot more in cellulose in the rest of the plant.  I may try to factor that in at some point.  This probably makes the picture much more favorable - but I suspect not so much that it's practically achievable.

Comment: There's still an error, I think: the daily human contribution of 1.27 * 10^3 g of CO2 should be divided by molar mass 4.4 * 10^1 g which yields 2.9 * 10^1 mol = 1.8 * 10^25 molecules of CO2